# Clarification on ethereum block number

Tags: go-ethereum, balances

When we are searching to update the balance on ethereum we got this link Click [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/511/why-is-geth-always-returning-a-0-balance). But now in our server the latest block number is above 1900000 but till now we didn't get update the balance. When we look at the ethereum.io website it shows 2300000 on transaction. so please explain how it works and when it will update?

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction that created the balance occurred after block 1900000, then it wouldn't have happened yet (according to your local node). Etherscan.io (did you mean etherscan.io or ethereum.io?) is always up to date (mostly), so if there's a balance there, then there will be a balance on the local server once it catches up. Your node is not synced.